# cant remove cordova RECORD_AUDIO permission

Tags: android, cordova

I removed the RECORD_AUDIO permission from the AndroidManifest.xml and android.json...

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="0.0.1" package="com.runesware.betterapp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:name="de.appplant.cordova.plugin.background.ForegroundService" />
        <receiver android:exported="false" android:name="de.appplant.cordova.plugin.localnotification.TriggerReceiver" />
        <receiver android:exported="false" android:name="de.appplant.cordova.plugin.localnotification.ClearReceiver" />
        <activity android:exported="false" android:launchMode="singleInstance" android:name="de.appplant.cordova.plugin.localnotification.ClickActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay" />
        <receiver android:exported="false" android:name="de.appplant.cordova.plugin.notification.TriggerReceiver" />
        <receiver android:exported="false" android:name="de.appplant.cordova.plugin.notification.ClearReceiver" />
        <receiver android:exported="false" android:name="de.appplant.cordova.plugin.localnotification.RestoreReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <activity android:exported="false" android:launchMode="singleInstance" android:name="de.appplant.cordova.plugin.notification.ClickActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay" />
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="22" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
</manifest>


----android.json---
    {
        "prepare_queue": {
            "installed": [],
            "uninstalled": []
        },
        "config_munge": {
            "files": {
                "res/xml/config.xml": {
                    "parents": {
                        "/*": [
                            {
                                "xml": "<preference name=\"webView\" value=\"org.crosswalk.engine.XWalkWebViewEngine\" />",
                                "count": 1
                            },
                            {
                                "xml": "<feature name=\"File\"><param name=\"android-package\" value=\"org.apache.cordova.file.FileUtils\" /><param name=\"onload\" value=\"true\" /></feature>",
                                "count": 1
                            },
                            {
                                "xml": "<feature name=\"InAppBrowser\"><param name=\"android-package\" value=\"org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser.InAppBrowser\" /></feature>",
                                "count": 1
                            },
                            {
                                "xml": "<feature name=\"Whitelist\"><param name=\"android-package\" value=\"org.apache.cordova.whitelist.WhitelistPlugin\" /><param name=\"onload\" value=\"true\" /></feature>",
                                "count": 1
                            },
                            {
                                "xml": "<feature name=\"Device\"><param name=\"android-package\" value=\"org.apache.cordova.device.Device\" /></feature>",
                                "count": 1
                            },
                            {
                                "xml": "<feature name=\"BackgroundMode\"><param name=\"android-package\" value=\"de.appplant.cordova.plugin.background.BackgroundMode\" /></feature>",
                                "count": 1
                            },
                            {
                                "xml": "<preference name=\"KeepRunning\" value=\"true\" />",
                                "count": 1
                            },
                            {
                                "xml": "<feature name=\"LocalNotification\"><param name=\"android-package\" value=\"de.appplant.cordova.plugin.localnotification.LocalNotification\" /></feature>",
                                "count": 1
                            },
                            {
                                "xml": "<feature name=\"Suspend\"><param name=\"android-package\" value=\"org.android.tools.Suspend\" /></feature>",
                                "count": 1
                            },
                            {
                                "xml": "<feature name=\"Notification\"><param name=\"android-package\" value=\"org.apache.cordova.dialogs.Notification\" /></feature>",
                                "count": 1
                            },
                            {
                                "xml": "<feature name=\"Vibration\"><param name=\"android-package\" value=\"org.apache.cordova.vibration.Vibration\" /></feature>",
                                "count": 1
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "config.xml": {
                    "parents": {
                        "/*": [
                            {
                                "xml": "<preference name=\"AndroidPersistentFileLocation\" value=\"Internal\" />",
                                "count": 1
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "AndroidManifest.xml": {
                    "parents": {
                        "/*": [
                            {
                                "xml": "<uses-permission android:name=\"android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE\" />",
                                "count": 1
                            }
                        ],
                        "/manifest/application": [
                            {
                                "xml": "<service android:name=\"de.appplant.cordova.plugin.background.ForegroundService\" />",
                                "count": 1
                            },
                            {
                                "xml": "<receiver android:exported=\"false\" android:name=\"de.appplant.cordova.plugin.localnotification.TriggerReceiver\" />",
                                "count": 1
                            },
                            {
                                "xml": "<receiver android:exported=\"false\" android:name=\"de.appplant.cordova.plugin.localnotification.ClearReceiver\" />",
                                "count": 1
                            },
                            {
                                "xml": "<activity android:exported=\"false\" android:launchMode=\"singleInstance\" android:name=\"de.appplant.cordova.plugin.localnotification.ClickActivity\" android:theme=\"@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay\" />",
                                "count": 1
                            },
                            {
                                "xml": "<receiver android:exported=\"false\" android:name=\"de.appplant.cordova.plugin.notification.TriggerReceiver\" />",
                                "count": 1
                            },
                            {
                                "xml": "<receiver android:exported=\"false\" android:name=\"de.appplant.cordova.plugin.notification.ClearReceiver\" />",
                                "count": 1
                            },
                            {
                                "xml": "<receiver android:exported=\"false\" android:name=\"de.appplant.cordova.plugin.localnotification.RestoreReceiver\"><intent-filter><action android:name=\"android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED\" /></intent-filter></receiver>",
                                "count": 1
                            },
                            {
                                "xml": "<activity android:exported=\"false\" android:launchMode=\"singleInstance\" android:name=\"de.appplant.cordova.plugin.notification.ClickActivity\" android:theme=\"@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay\" />",
                                "count": 1
                            }
                        ],
                        "/manifest": [
                            {
                                "xml": "<uses-permission android:name=\"android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED\" />",
                                "count": 1
                            },
                            {
                                "xml": "<uses-permission android:name=\"android.permission.VIBRATE\" />",
                                "count": 1
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "installed_plugins": {
            "com.msopentech.indexedDB": {
                "PACKAGE_NAME": "com.runesware.betterapp"
            },
            "cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview": {
                "PACKAGE_NAME": "com.runesware.betterapp"
            },
            "cordova-plugin-file": {
                "PACKAGE_NAME": "com.runesware.betterapp"
            },
            "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": {
                "PACKAGE_NAME": "com.runesware.betterapp"
            },
            "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {
                "PACKAGE_NAME": "com.runesware.betterapp"
            },
            "de.appplant.cordova.plugin.background-mode": {
                "PACKAGE_NAME": "com.runesware.betterapp"
            },
            "de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification": {
                "PACKAGE_NAME": "com.runesware.betterapp"
            },
            "org.android.tools.suspend": {
                "PACKAGE_NAME": "com.runesware.betterapp"
            },
            "org.apache.cordova.console": {
                "PACKAGE_NAME": "com.runesware.betterapp"
            },
            "org.apache.cordova.dialogs": {
                "PACKAGE_NAME": "com.runesware.betterapp"
            },
            "org.apache.cordova.vibration": {
                "PACKAGE_NAME": "com.runesware.betterapp"
            }
        },
        "dependent_plugins": {
            "org.apache.cordova.device": {
                "PACKAGE_NAME": "com.runesware.betterapp"
            }
        }
    }
```

on installation no redord audio permission is requested but after installation in settings RECORD_AUDIO permission is shown -.-

i cant post pictures... heresome links

http://www.xup.in/dl,52994846/Screenshot_2015-10-01-11-07-24.png/

http://www.xup.in/dl,79413167/Screenshot_2015-10-01-11-08-25.png/

plugins used

- com.msopentech.indexedDB 0.1.2 "IndexedDB polyfill"
- com.tonikorin.cordova.plugin.autostart 1.2.1 "Autostart"
- cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview 1.2.0 "Crosswalk WebView Engine"
- cordova-plugin-file 3.0.0 "File"
- cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 1.0.1 "InAppBrowser"
- cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.0.0 "Whitelist"
- de.appplant.cordova.plugin.background-mode 0.6.3 "BackgroundMode"
- de.appplant.cordova.plugin.badge 0.7.1 "Cordova Badge Plugin"
- de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification 0.8.1"LocalNotification"
- org.android.tools.suspend 0.1.2 "Android Suspend"
- org.apache.cordova.console 0.2.13 "Console"
- org.apache.cordova.device 0.3.0 "Device"
- org.apache.cordova.dialogs 0.3.0 "Notification"
- org.apache.cordova.vibration 0.3.13 "Vibration"

Comment: What plugins you installed?

Comment: i dont use any plugin that requires RECORD_AUDIO

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue before as well. If I'm understanding your problem accurately, Google is throwing an error requesting you remove the audio permissions, but then probably crashes immediately after you remove it. Add the code back and follow below.

Add `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"` to the manifest line like so:

```
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="0.0.1" package="com.runesware.betterapp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
```

Then, inside your RECORD_AUDIO permission, add `tools:node="remove"` like below:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" tools:node="remove" />`

You may also need to add `tools:node="remove"` to the camera permission as well.